# How to sum amount between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, datetime, where-clause

I have a table which have `'user_id', 'amount', 'today_date'` fields. I just want to sum all the `amount` grouping by `user_id` by the dates between today and last 6 days. I am storing all the dates in `'today_date'`

I have tried something like this :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days'));

$data['this_week'] = $this->db->select('sum(amount) as total, user_id')->where("today_date BETWEEN $date AND $week")->group_by('user_id')->get('tbl_transcations')->result_array();
```

I may lack in CI syntax as I have started 2 days earlier.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have the date bounds in the wrong order. This:

```
->where("today_date BETWEEN $date AND $week")
```

Should be:

```
->where("today_date BETWEEN '$week' AND '$date'")
```

Note that you need single quotes around the literal dates.

You could very well drop the variables and do the computation directly in the database:

```
->where("today_date BETWEEN current_date - interval 6 day AND current_date")
```

If your dates have a time component, then using half-open intervals is a better strategy:

```
->where("today_date >= current_date - interval 6 day and today_date < current_date + interval 1 day")
```

Comment: Showing error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`day` AND current_date AND

Comment: when using your second query

Comment: Unknown column '2020-10-02' in 'where clause'

SELECT sum(amount) as total, `user_id` FROM `tbl_transcations` WHERE `today_date` BETWEEN `2020-10-02` AND 2020-10-08 AND `type` = '0' AND `txn_mode` = 'Game' GROUP BY `user_id`

Comment: @BhaweshBhakar: you need single quotes around the literal dates. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: ok, is there a way so that I can convert 2020-06-04 10:20:03 to 2020-06-04 and then check in condition in above code

Comment: ->where("cast([created_at] as date) as [created_at] BETWEEN '$week' AND '$date'")

Comment: Tried something like above

Comment: @BhaweshBhakar: you did not tell that your dates have time components... You can cast to date with just `date(created_at)` - but it is more efficient to use half-open intervals. See my update.